# Change comma per dot in price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how can change the , per . in price??

I have this code

```
<div class="product-view-cash-price-div product-view-cash-price text-webstore">
            <span class="product-view-cash-price-value text-webstore" itemprop="price" content="<?php echo @number_format($variation_product->get_price()); ?>" style="font-size:35px;">
            $<?php echo @number_format($variation_product->get_price()); ?>
            </span>
            <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="CLP"></span>
        </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the thousand and decimal separator for the prices in your shop right in the WooCommerce settings. Via WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency options.

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Don't work ...  is a custom php price.

Comment: You will have to format it with `wc_price()` to see your WooCommerce price format settings. So use: `wc_price( $variation_product->get_price() )`